# select first x records per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Am using the query below to search for products that contain a term in their title. The query returns the desired results (often too many results).

Now I only want it to be able choose a maximum of 3 (random) products per company. Some companies return many records/products, but I only need to take 3 and move on to the next company

```
SELECT p.title As entryname, cname 
FROM company c, product p
WHERE p.title LIKE '%steel%' AND p.cid = c.cid 
GROUP By cname, ca.title
```

I tried to understand the partition by and rank thing but I did not get too far. I am using ms sql

Comment: Do you really mean random rather than arbitrary? Also what database are you targeting. The solutions to this problem or DB specific

Comment: Conrad, Am using MS SQL web edition. By random, I mean the first 3 selected products do not have to be the same all... If the are 100 products for company x, any 3 of the 100 can do

Comment: Ok well since WEB edition didn't start until 2008 to the best of my knowledge, I've added the tags to your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to do this

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
    p.title as entryname, cname,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY p.id) rn
FROM company c
    INNER JOIN  product p 
    ON  p.cid = c.cid 
WHERE p.title LIKE '%steel%'
GROUP By cname, ca.title    
)
SELECT 
    p.title as entryname, cname,
FROM CTE where rn <= 3
```

If you really want random (instead of the 3 with the lowest ID) you can change the row_number line to

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id order by newid()) rn`

Answer (score 0):

If your database is SQL Server (going off of ms sql at the end of your post), look up [TOP on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP(3) p.title As entryname, cname 
FROM company c, product p
WHERE p.title LIKE '%steel%' AND p.cid = c.cid 
GROUP By cname, ca.title
```

For Oracle, you would use [rownum](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT p.title As entryname, cname 
FROM company c, product p
WHERE p.title LIKE '%steel%' AND p.cid = c.cid AND rownum < 4
GROUP By cname, ca.title
```

Comment: the OP wants TOP 3 products per company.

Comment: DuraCell, this only returns the TOP3 of the whole collection. It should return 1 2 or max 3 products for each company

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append

```
limit 3,5
```

to the end of your query. This will give you **sequencially**  5 rows starting at row 3, as an example.

Now to chose these 5 rows **randonly** is something mode complex, i guess.

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, it turns out is SQL Server. Also its wrong, the op wants 3 products per company not just 3 from all companies so adding limit 3,5 wouldn't do it

Comment: @ConradFrix. Yeah, you are right, it's wrong. Next time I'll read the question two times. Thanks!